# Google Sheets IMPORTXML error: Import Internal Error

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm facing a weird error while trying import data from this link: https://www.atproperties.com/472719
using XPath //li[@class="active"] I'm confused cause there is no problem getting data from a similar source: https://www.atproperties.com/370926 using the same XPath. Both hyperlinks are opening the same way in chrome browser and have the same XPath. Here is the [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MQaZFNgiJW1E9X_4MW1DYn4UUy_CoNla7ohbP9wCTbI/edit?usp=sharing) to the spreadsheet.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IMPORTDATA`, `INDEX` and `REGEXEXTRACT` for this specific case :

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(INDEX(IMPORTDATA(B2);9;1);" - (.+)")&", "&INDEX(IMPORTDATA(B2);9;2)
```

Output :

[image: IMPD]

Side note : your XPath should be fixed as followed : `(//li[@class="active"])[1]`